# Flash Movieclips children Lost

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a empty movieclip container in which I add movieclips as children. But when I try to get the children it does not trace/return anything. Here is my code.

```
// Creating Container
var competencyContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
competencyContainer.name = "competencyContainer";
this.addChild(competencyContainer);

var lastx:Number = 200;
function createUsers(){

// Creating movieclips
for (var i:Number=0; i<globals.scoreList.length;i++)
{
    var test:MovieClip = new userbox();
    test.x= lastx;
    lastx = lastx+104.3;    
    test.name = String(i);
    competencyContainer.addChild(test);
}

}

function moveRight(eventObject:MouseEvent){

trace("right Pressed");
trace(competencyContainer);
for(var childName in competencyContainer){
    trace("child movieclip: " + competencyContainer[childName]);

}
```

The movieclips are made perfectly on screen and do not give an error. The above code runs. But does not show the

```
trace("child movieclip: " + competencyContainer[childName]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
function moveRight(eventObject:MouseEvent)
{

    trace("right Pressed");
    var test:Number = competencyContainer.numChildren;
    trace(competencyContainer.numChildren);
    for(var i:Number = 0; i < test; i++)
    {
      var children:DisplayObject = competencyContainer.getChildAt(i);
      trace(children.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`getChildByName`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29) function...

```
trace("child movieclip: " + competencyContainer.getChildByName(childName));
```

Comment: Done that I added the trace later. First I was changing their X-cordinates by getChildByName which was not working.